# Determine $\int_a^b \frac{f'(x)}{\cos^2(f(x))}e^{\tan(f(x))}dx$ with the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

> Determine $$\int_a^b \frac{f'(x)}{\cos^2(f(x))}e^{\tan(f(x))}dx$$ (for $\frac \pi 2+ k\pi \not\in f([a,b])$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$) with the fundamental theorem of calculus.

How to do this? I'm familiar with integrals of explicitly given functions, but this is new to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember (or prove) that $\tan'(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$. Make the substitution $u=\tan(f(x))$ to obtain $du=\frac{f'(x)}{\cos^2(f(x))}dx$. Therefore, you will come up with the integral $\int_{\tan(f(a))}^{\tan(f(b))} e^udu$, which is easily solved.

Comment: Very clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

well using $u=f(x)$ we get $dx=\frac{du}{f'(x)}$. This would give us $\sec^2(u)e^{\tan(u)}du$ which is of the form $g'(u)e^{g(u)}du$ and so is easily solveable.